# Передать null как ref int

Tags: c#, .net, аргументы

Смотрю описание [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0). Сигнатура метода:

```
public static int Increment (ref int location);
```

А вот дальше написано:

> **Исключения**
> NullReferenceException
> Адрес `location` является указателем `null`.

Что-то я не понимаю, что надо передать в качестве аргумента, чтобы значение адреса оказалось `null`. Это вообще возможно на C#? Как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно вот так

```cs
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    ref int p = ref *(int*)null;
    try
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref p);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Ну вы синхронные)) Галочка именно тебе за объявление ref-переменной)

Answer (score 3):

Да запросто!

```
unsafe
{
    int* p = null;
    Interlocked.Increment(ref *p);
}
```

Stack trace в исключении показывает

> at System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(Int32& location)
> at TestApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 27

— то есть упала именно функция `Interlocked.Increment`, а не разыменование нулевого указателя.

Ещё один метод, без `unsafe`-блоков:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref Unsafe.NullRef<int>());
```

---

Ну а в чистом C#, без интеропа, `Marshal` и тому подобных штук это, конечно, невозможно.