# Когда происходит выделение памяти под переменную?

Tags: c#, память

если я объявил переменную но не присвоил ей значение, например `int i;` память в стеке под нее выделяется сразу или только когда ей присвоится какое-либо значение?

Comment: такие детали вполне могут быть реализованы по-разному в разных компиляторах. // да даже и в одном, но в разных ситуациях.

Comment: не стоит так радикально менять смысл вопроса. в особенности после того, как на предыдущую редакцию кто-то уже дал ответ. // лучше задать новый с помощью соответствующей кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: Один вопрос - одна тема. Не меняйте кардинально так вопрос, создайте новый. Откатил назад к исходной версии. Ваш текст сможете найти в истории правок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1329050/revisions

Comment: В машинном коде переменной вовсе может не быть. Число может быть помещено в регистр процессора.

Comment: Рекомендую переставить галку, появился более точный и правильный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ваших терминах - "сразу". И будет ей присвоено значение по умолчанию для типа int - то есть ноль. (А например для классов таким значением по умолчанию является null)

Вы вполне могли бы провести натурный эксперимент, накидав простой код типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень полезно писать такие простенькие скетчи - это даёт вам возможность лучше понимать, как устроена система, придумывать свои собственные простые кейсы для проверки и научиться писать код из головы.

Comment: Слушайте, а я правильно понял, что это не классический отладчик "студии"? Там вроде нет IL и других вещей, котрые видны на картинке. А что это за тулза?

Comment: @S.H. Верно. Это linqpad - очень легковесная мини-IDE для быстрого прототипирования, весьма рекомендую, особенно её метод .Dump() для очень наглядного вывода на экран.

Comment: @Димас Все когда-то не умели, научитесь: это вопрос мотивации, времени и упорства. Очень важный навык для программиста, рекомендую прокачивать постепенно.

Comment: @AK - спасибо! ну, вот у меня вертелось на языке, что это новенький LinqPad - я еще старым пользовался, там вроде как такого не было...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245901/373567 если значимая переменная не инициализирована, она не имеет значения по умолчанию. То есть код `int i; i++;` не скомпилируется. Выделения памяти под локальную переменную вообще может не произойти, в роли такой переменной может участвовать регистр процессора. О выделении памяти ваш ответ корректен для полей класса и объектов, но не для локальных переменных, хранящих значения или ссылки на объекты. Почему так себя ведет LinqPad - загадка, но он явно не отражает реальную суть происходящего.

Comment: При объявлении переменной задачется ее сематическая область видимости, а вот само значение переменной, как и сама переменная, задается при первом присваивании. То есть грубо говоря при объявлении переменной ничего и нигде не выделяется. Именно поэтому я пишу здесь такие длинные комментарии. С полями - да, там другая логика. Значение по умолчанию полю класса присваивается в любом случае при объявлении, если оно не задано явно или не присвоено в конструкторе класса.

Answer (score 7):

На такие *простые* вопросы всегда невероятно трудно ответить. Потому что простого и короткого ответа нет.

Начнём с того, что компиляция кода c# проходит несколько стадий: сперва в IL-код, потом в машинный код. И память под *переменную* где-то там выделяется в обоих случаях.

Возможно, говоря "переменная", вы имели в виду вообще любую программную сущность: это может быть и поле класса, и параметр метода.

Рассмотрим такой код:

```
class Test
{
    int instanceField;

    static int staticField;

    public void Foo(int param)
    {
        int variableA = 42;
        Console.WriteLine(variableA);
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        int variableB = 42;

        var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(x => x == variableB);

        Console.WriteLine(range.Count());
    }
}
```

Память под поле `instanceField` будет выделена при создании экземпляра класса. Скорей всего она будет в куче, но в последниях версиях .NET появился Escape analysis и память под объект в некоторых случаях может быть выделена на стеке.

Память под *статическое* поле `staticField` будет выделена, если я не ошибаюсь, при загрузке сборки.

Память под параметр `param` будет выделена при вызове метода. В зависимости от соглашений о вызове (Calling convention), рантайма (CLR, Mono) и уровня оптимизаций (Debug, Release) она может быть в стеке, в регистре, или бог знает где ещё.

Память под локальную переменную `variableA` будет выделена, скорее всего, в момент компиляции (JIT или AOT) метода `Foo`. На стеке или в регистре. Но если, например, убрать или закомментировать вызов `Console.WriteLine(variableA);`, то компилятор может выкинуть эту неиспользуемую переменную, в итоге память под неё вообще никогда не будет выделяться.

А ещё в последних версиях дотнета есть Tiered compilation. В ходе неё сперва может быть быстро выдан слабооптимизированный код (память под переменную выделена в одном месте), потом код может быть перекомпилирован в сильнооптимизированный (память выделена в другом месте).

С переменной `variableB` всё ещё интереснее! Она участвует в *замыкании*. В результате компилятором будет создан класс, содержащий эту переменную в качестве поля. Соответственно, память будет выделена в момент создания экземпляра этого класса.

В общем, всё сложно.
[The Truth About Value Types](https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/) - предлагаю ознакомиться с этой статьёй.

Comment: Ссылки на упомянутые термины нужны? Или заинтересовавшиеся сами нагуглят?

Comment: ссылки всегда нужны.

Comment: О, а вот и более правильное объяснение с нюансами подъхало!