# Как хранится массив структур?

Tags: c#

Как хранятся данные массив структур и классов. То есть, массив это ссылочный тип, а структура значимый, то есть хранится в стеке. И еще массивы структур в бенчмарке занимают место в куче, хотя не должны, ведь они должны храниться в стеке. Куда ссылаются ссылки массива? И тем же макаром объясните массив классов.

Comment: А почему вы решили что массив - это ссылочный тип?
Там по-другому: массив хранит указатели на объекты, если объекты ссылочные - они в куче, а если значимые - в стеке

Comment: @Lenz массив это и есть ссылочный тип, а так вы правы

Comment: @Lenz - _значимые - в стеке_ - классическая ошибка. Локальные переменные значимых типов хранятся на стеке. А поля классов и элементы коллекций - в куче, даже если они значимые.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1329097/184217 - всё намного сложнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просто запутались, распутаться легко.

Значимый тип - это кусок памяти с данными, например `int` это 4 байта, представляющие число. `int` это структура. Для массива интов CLR выделяет `N * 4` байт памяти.

Ссылочный тип состоит из 2 частей: ссылка и сам объект. Ссылка - это тот же по сути `int`, те же правила, значимый тип. Разница только в том что тип `IntPtr`, который используется для ссылок в 32-битных приложениях имеет размер 4 байта, а в 64-битных - 8 байт.

То есть грубо говоря массив любых ссылочных объектов `object[]` это мехнически ни что иное, как `IntPtr[]`. Другими словами, массив хранит только ссылки и тип для этих ссылок в своих метаданных. Сам же тип данных в массиве никак не влияет на его поведение. Любой `[]` массив хранит данные только в куче.

Утверждение, что значимые типы могут храниться только в стеке неверно, они могут храниться и в стеке и в куче, здесь нет никаких ограничений.

Comment: Разве ref struct хранится и в куче?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja Если вы про ссылки - это на усмотрение компилятора, а если про данные, то где угодно может храниться, `Span<byte> a = new byte[42];` - куча, `Span<byte> b = stackalloc byte[42];` - стек. Все ограничения `ref struct` связаны только с тем, куда указывает этот `ref`, и если на стек, то его нельзя уносить за пределы метода, иначе можно повредить этот самый стек или данные в нем. Если же `ref` указывает на кучу, то просто взяли сам объект из кучи, унесли ссылку на него куда угодно и там снова заспавнили `ref`, если требуется.

Comment: @Kalmankantaja `ref struct` логически делает ссылочный тип из значимого. Но так как значимые типы могут лежать в стеке, именно из этого и рисуются всякого рода ограничения. А сама по себе `ref` это тот же самый `int`, но толку от `ref`, если она начинает указывать на несущестсующую область в памяти, верно? Никакого. Поэтому `ref` можно передать методам вглубь, но нельзя передать наверх, так как того участка стека, на который этот `ref` указывает, наверху попросту нет, потому что стек будет очищен при возврате из метода. По этой же причине нельзя в полях хранить рефы и в асинхронных методах.

Comment: @Kalmankantaja можно ли положить референс на стек в поле и хранить в куче? Можно, правда только используя `unsafe` код, и я даже могу показать как. Если вам интересно, задайте вопрос, я отвечу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1442968/422180

Comment: `Span<byte>` будет храниться в стеке, поскольку является `Span` является `ref struct`. Структуры помеченные как ref только в стеке хранятся

Comment: @Kalmankantaja `ref struct` это не структура, это ссылка на структуру. А где могут храниться структуры? Да где угодно. И только из-за этого "где угодно" к ним применяются ограничения как для данным из стека, по наихудшему сценарию. Но это совершенно не значит, что `ref struct` не может указывать на кучу. А сама `ref` - это просто число. Я уже выше об этом писал.

Comment: я не про синтаксис вроде `method(ref int a)`, я про `ref struct MyStruct { }`. Тип `MyStruct` будет храниться только в стеке. По этой причине вы не сможете в условном классе/НЕ ref структуре объявить поле `private Span<byte> _span`. Но это можно сделать в методе, поскольку локальные переменные хранятся в стеке

Comment: @Kalmankantaja верно, но это ограничение касается только самого типа в безопасном синтаксисе. Никто не мешает вам имея адрес в памяти использовать этот же указатель в другом классе или методе или хранить в поле. Создавая спан вы не выполняете код на процессоре по факту, вы сообщаете компилятору, что хотите работать с данным куском памяти как с данными определенного типа в массиве определенной длинны. А компилятор сгенерит код работы с этими данными на основе типа и длины спана, только и всего. Поэтому хранить спаны в полях и передавать их куда-либо не просто нельзя, а в этом нет смысла.

Comment: @Kalmankantaja вы использовали когда-нибудь `MemoryMarshal.Cast`? Если нет, поизучайте, это может пригодиться, например работать с массивом байт как с массивом интов или вообще с комплексной структурой не копируя данные в памяти вообще. Есть еще `Unsafe.As` и прочие красивые штуки для того чтобы писать очень-очень быстрый код.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос только в том, будет память выделена заранее в стеке сразу или она будет выделена по необходимости еще одним дополнительным обращением к системе за ресурсами.

Смотрите на исходный тип самой переменной. Если он значимый - значит память заранее выделится и будет лежать в стеке как значение. Если он ссылочный, то память выделится ровно под ссылку, заполнять вы её будете отдельным обращением за ресурсами.

Переменная для массива ссылочная - значит память выделится под ссылку, сам массив отдельным запросом. Создали массив - какие в нём переменные будут? Если значимые, значит массив со значениями. Если ссылочные - значит массив ссылок и всё остальное опять же отдельным запросом к системе.

Понимать это надо только для того, что считать время и потребляемую память. Каждое значение на стеке это плюс память. Каждое значение в куче это плюс время за запрос ресурсов у системы.

А дальше вы уже можете играть в матрешку, создать объект в котором есть структура, у которой есть ссылка на объект, у которой есть структура и т.д. Опять же единственный вопрос, будет ли память выделена сразу под данные или только под ссылку (а данные уже отдельно запрашиваются по необходимости).

```
struct StackMemory 
{
    public HeapMemory heap;
}

class HeapMemory 
{
    public StackMemory stack;
}

class Program
{
    StackMemory stack;
    
    private void Run() 
    {
        stack.heap = new HeapMemory();
        stack.heap.stack.heap = new HeapMemory();
        stack.heap.stack.heap.stack.heap = new HeapMemory();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run();
}
```

Запросили new HeapMemory() - место под StackMemory выделилось сразу с запросом в котором только место под ссылку на следующую HeapMemory. И так по кругу. Еще учитывайте, что это примерное поведение, на самом деле программа не обязана вам сразу выделять память в стеке и спокойно может хранить его где-то в куче.

Comment: `int a = new int()` оно обычно не пишется, но генерится компилятором автоматически. То есть данный код сахарный и скрывает часть реальной работы кода. Его можно написать более очевидным способом. Но выглядит прикольно, согласен.