# Можно ли положить ссылку на стек в поле и хранить в куче

Tags: c#, стек, куча

Как можно ли положить референс на стек в поле и хранить в куче?

Comment: 1) зачем? 2) что вообще? приведите пример - о чём это, собственно

Comment: Наверное нужно было бы дать ссылку на источник вопроса, почему он возник из этого комментария: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442931/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80/1442964#comment2575459_1442952

Comment: Думаю, вопрос возник из-за желания писать эффективный код. [Write safe and efficient C# code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code) - рекомендую всем, если кто ещё не читал.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, но только осторожно.

Ссылка на область в памяти - это `IntPtr`/`UIntPtr`, число. А что можно делать с числами, вы знаете. Правда чтобы достать это число, придется использовать небезопасный код, потому что разработчики .NET неплохо позаботились о том, чтобы вы не попортили себе данные в стеке.

**Данный трюк выполнен профессионалом, не пытайтесь повторить это дома.**

```
unsafe class MyClass
{
    private IntPtr ptr;

    public byte[] Method1(ManualResetEventSlim evt, ManualResetEventSlim init)
    {
        Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[4]; // аллокация 4 байт в стеке
        fixed (void* p = span) // получаю указатель
        {
            ptr = new IntPtr(p); // сохраняю его в поле
            init.Set(); // сообщаю вызвающему коду, что я готов принять данные
            evt.Wait(); // жду, когда вызывающий код закончит запись
        }
        return span.ToArray(); // копирую данные в обычный массив и возвращаю
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Span<byte> span = new Span<byte>(ptr.ToPointer(), 4); // делаю спан из указателя
        for (byte i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
        {
            span[i] = i; // записываю в него данные
        }
    }
}
```

Вызывающий код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    ManualResetEventSlim evt = new();
    ManualResetEventSlim init = new();
    Task<byte[]> task = Task.Run(() => myClass.Method1(evt, init));
    init.Wait();
    myClass.Method2();
    evt.Set();
    byte[] result = task.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
0,1,2,3
```

Фактически данный код показывает, как из одного потока что-то записать в стек другому потоку. Совершенно бессмысленная операция, есть более простые и заурядные способы передачи данных, но вы спросили, возможно ли сделать ссылку на стек, я показал как.

Но вряд-ли это имеет какую-либо практическую ценность, разве только что для какой-то очень сильно специфичной задачи для многопоточки, которая требует очень высокой производительности и очень хочется избежать частых аллокаций памяти для передачи данных между потоками, и даже в таком случае есть другие, более удобные варианты решения.

Скажем так: стек - это очень быстрое хранилище небольшого объема данных для метода в одном каком-то конкретном потоке. Использовать его в многопоточке как общую память - опасно, можно очень легко накосячить с потокобезопасностью, будьте предельно внимательны.

Comment: Нифига себе, +1 знание которым буду терроризировать младшего брата через полгода