# Где храниться ссылочный тип (строка) в структуре?

Tags: c#, struct, стек

Объясните заблудшему в терабайтах инфы о C#) Если я в структуре объявляю поле с типом string, то где оно будет хранится, в стеке (т.к. структура значимый тип) или же в управляемой куче т.к. строка ссылочный тип. Не могу понять. Или в случае объявление строки в структуре она приобретает свойство значимого типа.

Comment: Строка - в куче. Ссылка на неё - в структуре. А где будет храниться сама структура, так просто не скажешь, она может быть и на стеке, и в куче (если сама является частью другого типа).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1329097/184217 - гляньте это. Когда-нибудь я добавлю там ссылки...