# Как хранятся значимые и ссылочные типы в C#

Tags: c#

Самым распространённым ответом на этот вопрос является, что значение значимых типов хранятся в стеке, а ссылочных в куче. Но оказывается там всё обстоит сложнее.

Я решил полистать Рихтера и наткнулся на момент где в книге объясняется, что делает оператор new(), однако там объяснено как он выделает память для ссылочных типов, но ничего не сказано про значимые. Я запутался, помогите)

Comment: А зачем это нужно?

Comment: См. [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c/) А именно [Under the Hood of .NET Memory Management, Chris Farrell, Nick Harrison. Полное описание всех тонкостей управления памятью в платформе .NET. Книга доступна бесплатно на английском.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/RedGateBooks/ChrisFarrell/Under_the_Hood_of_NET_Management.pdf)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1329097/184217 - запутаю немного (злорадный смех)

Comment: Тоже запутаю: `int a = 0;` и `int a = new int();` это 2 эквивалентные записи. `new` лезет в кучу только при создании объектов. При создании структур это будет либо стек, либо регистр процессора для числовых примитивов. Например тот же `new int()` по факту ничего не выделяет ни в стеке, не в куче, а просто присваивает значение регистру процессора для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Постановка вопроса некорректна вследствие as-if rule. Пример: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUETgASa4DsRA3kaQ+bgGzkAspAstDABQCU9RnUKMxpAG4QATqQgATeQFNZAXlIwlAd1IBBRSt4BmOKTb8A3EPFMAnLwXLpAOgDiShAMvXSAXyL+xIQoCNIArgDGCHoG0rQ+0koKAPYwADYAnqSw0QAephlWooyYRjFOvDmk+dkw0RmCxQwiNgwIABZQKM65pOq5Ra2kHV3OWeqFPoFiPqW10e6e/H0AfNWkANSkk4S+QA=== Посмотрите на ассемблерный код и скажите, где хранится создаваемый в `Main` экземпляр структуры `Adder`?